# Function not disabling NEXT button

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to do validation in AngularJS. I want to do max and min validation. I have wrote function for that and called that function in HTML file. Function is displaying the error message but it fails to disable the next button and its accepting the wrong input. here is my funtion

```
$scope.validate = function(NetProfit) {
    if (NetProfit < 100000 || NetProfit > 20000000) 
    {
        $scope.greeting = 'Please enter a value between 100000 and 20000000.';        
    } 
    else 
    {
        $scope.greeting = '';        
    }
};
```

here is my html code

```
<input ng-model="NetProfit" name="NetProfit" id="NetProfit" type="text" ng-pattern="/^\d+$/" ng-change='validate(NetProfit)' class="zoomIn" placeholder="Your Annual Net Profit" required>
<p class="ErrorMessage">
    {{greeting}}
</p>
<p class="ErrorMessage" ng-show="step5form.NetProfit.$error.pattern">
    Annual net profit cannot be characters.
</p>
<button class="Submit" ng-disabled="!step5form.$valid" ng-click="step = 6">Next</button>
```

Comment: I suppose you mean it's not disabling if your netprofit is < 100000 or > 200000. But there's no validation involved (just showing a message).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you dont want to change your whole code simply add below `||` (OR) condition to your NEXT button.

```
<button class="Submit" ng-disabled="!step5form.$valid || greeting!='' " ng-click="step = 6">Next</button>
```

here is working plunk 
https://plnkr.co/edit/yOdQO2TMxjmLVV14u5ub?p=preview